# Nusoap WSDL requests not working properly

Tags: xml, nusoap

I'm having problems getting the results I want from the WSDL.

My script:

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/lib/classes/class.glssoap.php');

$glssoap = new GLSSoap;

echo "<pre>";
//print_r($glssoap->GetOneParcelShop(96101)); // SUCCESS
//print_r($glssoap->GetAllParcelShops()); // SUCCESS
print_r($glssoap->GetAllParcelShopsInZipcode(8000)); // FAILS : RETURNS  operation GetAllParcelShopsInZipcode not present.
print_r($glssoap->GetNearestParcelShops('Kriegersvej 8', '8000')); // FAILS : RETURNS  operation GetNearestParcelShops not present.
print_r($glssoap->SearchNearstParcelShops('Kriegersvej 8', '8000')); // FAILS : RETURNS  operation SearchNearstParcelShops not present.
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

The class:

```
<?php
class GLSSoap {

    //Get one ParcelShop 
    public function GetOneParcelShop($parcelShopNumber)
    {
        $gls_params = array();
        $gls_params['ParcelShopNumber'] = $parcelShopNumber;

        $result = $this->_soapcall('GetOneParcelShop', $gls_params);

        return $result;
    }

    //Returns all ParcelShops in Denmark 
    public function GetAllParcelShops()
    {   
        $gls_params = array();
        $result = $this->_soapcall('GetAllParcelShops', $gls_params);

        return $result;
    }

    //Returns all ParcelShops in a zipcode 
    public function GetAllParcelShopsInZipcode($zipCode)
    {   
        $gls_params = array();
        $gls_params['Zipcode'] = $zipCode;

        $result = $this->_soapcall('GetAllParcelShopsInZipcode', $gls_params);

        return $result;
    }

    //Search for the nearest ParcelShops to an address - Strict version - used for automated processing 
    public function GetNearestParcelShops($street, $zipCode, $amount = 4)
    {   
        $gls_params = array();
        $gls_params['Street'] = $street;
        $gls_params['zipcode'] = $zipCode;
        $gls_params['amount'] = $amount;

        $result = $this->_soapcall('GetNearestParcelShops', $gls_params);

        return $result;
    }

    //Search for the nearest ParcelShops to an address - Loose version - user should veryfi data 
    public function SearchNearstParcelShops($street, $zipCode, $amount = 4)
    {   
        $gls_params = array();
        $gls_params['Street'] = $street;
        $gls_params['zipcode'] = $zipCode;
        $gls_params['amount'] = $amount;

        $result = $this->_soapcall('SearchNearstParcelShops', $gls_params);

        return $result;
    }

    private function _soapcall($call, $params)
    {
        require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/class.nusoap.php');

        $soapclient = new nusoap_client('http://www.gls.dk/webservices_v2/wsPakkeshop.asmx?WSDL','wsdl');

        $result = $soapclient->call($call, array('parameters' => $params));

        /* Debug */
        echo '<h2>Request</h2><pre>' . htmlspecialchars($soapclient->request, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
        echo '<h2>Response</h2><pre>' . htmlspecialchars($soapclient->response, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
        //echo '<h2>Debug</h2><pre>' . htmlspecialchars($soapclient->debug_str, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); echo '</pre>';

        // Check for a fault
        if ($soapclient->fault) {
            echo '<div class="alert error"><h2>Fault</h2><pre>';
            print_r($result);
            echo '</pre></div>';
        } else {
            // Check for errors
            $err = $soapclient->getError();
            if ($err) {
                // Display the error
                echo '<div class="alert error"><h2>Error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre></div>';
            } else {
                return $result;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
};
?>
```

Further more I use the NUSOAP class as represented here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/

---

My problem is that GetAllParcelShopsInZipcode, GetNearestParcelShops & SearchNearestParcelShops all returns "operation X not present".

The service I'm using is located here: http://www.gls.dk/webservices_v2/wsPakkeshop.asmx

Can anyone please give me a hint what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone stumbling across this question at a later time, the problem lies with GLS documentation not being updated properly. Notice the names of the different methods at their online webservice.